# Check if a radio box is selected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a little show and hide logic.

I am looking to show a pay button, But only once a "package type" is selected.

I just cannot seem to get this to work.

**My HTML Code is as follows...**

```
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <img src="http://local.halo-smart/assets/img/icons/icon-package-one.png">
  <input type="radio" title="69" value="package1" name="bikes[]1" 
                      class="radio-price"> 
</label>
```

How can I check against this being selected?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [**`:checked`**](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector

```
$("input[name='bikes[]1']").is(':checked')
```

The above code will return `true` if the radio button is selected and vice versa.